# Group_concat showing limite result

Tags: mysql

Please help, i used group_concat to get comma separated numbers but it's only showing 72 out of over 3000 values.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `phone` ) 
FROM  `notify` 
LIMIT 0 , 4000
```

Answer (score 2):

The group_concat function has a maximum length [From [MySQL Documentation]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of
>   group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an
>   unsigned integer:  SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
>
> The return value is a nonbinary or binary string, depending on
>   whether the arguments are nonbinary or binary strings. The result type
>   is TEXT or BLOB unless group_concat_max_len is less than or equal to
>   512, in which case the result type is VARCHAR or VARBINARY.

But you probably shouldn't be doing what you are doing: it's better to just fetch the rows 1 by 1, and have your application join them into one comma-separated string.

Comment: What application are you using? Are you writing a program, what language?

Answer (score 1):

The group_concat result length is limited(truncated) to the value of the group_concat_max_len system variable. The default value of this variable is 1024.

If you want change the value of the variable the syntax is:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Comment: Please where do i add the SEt [Global... ?